# LoadLibrary can't find .dll in NetBeans

Tags: java, dll, netbeans, javabeans

I trying to load SFmpq.dll via this code

```
static {
    Native.setProtected(true);
    System.setProperty("jna.library.path",
            new File("lib").getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("jna.library.path"));
    INSTANCE = (SFmpq)   Native.loadLibrary("SFmpq", SFmpq.class);
}
```

It gets executed, Folder and File exist but I still get this error:

> C:\Users\Frotty\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Optimizer\lib Exception in
>   thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to
>   load library 'SFmpq': The specified module could not be found.

I gave the code and .dll a friend of mine who imported it into Eclipse and there it worked perfectly fine.
Can anyone spot my mistake or how do I import .dlls correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this error if you try to load a 32 bit library on a 64 bit system.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with using [System.load(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load%28java.lang.String%29) and [System.loadLibrary(..)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29) to load dlls